# Android studio migrating from Eclipse Manifest merge failed with multiple errors

Tags: android, eclipse

I was sent an Android project build in eclipse for me to make the migration to Android Studio, I import the project and everything is fine until I tried to run the app, at the end it throws me:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':microfinanzasOriginacion:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
```

I searched  several post but no answer worked for me, I hope you could help.

Libqactions Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="net.londatiga.android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

    </application>

</manifest>
```

MicrofinanzasOriginacion manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tsp.microriginacion"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:versionCode="7"
    android:versionName="2.0.0.5" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.tsp.microriginacion.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission  android:name="com.tsp.microriginacion.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.tsp.microriginacion.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
         android:name="com.tsp.microriginacion.sesion.DatosSesion"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo_bafar"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAmy5tz8P55iy6bXbtcpTMc65583OyL104" />

        <service android:name="com.tsp.microriginacion.services.GPSActualizacionUbicacionService">
        </service>

        <service android:name="com.tsp.microriginacion.services.SyncDatosService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"></service>

        <receiver android:name="com.tsp.microriginacion.services.AlarmProcesoCadaSegundo">
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="com.tsp.microriginacion.services.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
                <category android:name="com.tsp.microriginacion" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.tsp.microriginacion.services.GCMIntentService"></service>

         <activity
            android:name="com.tsp.microriginacion.vista.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

         <activity
            android:name="com.tsp.microriginacion.vista.MenuPrincipal"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_menu_principal"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.tsp.microriginacion.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
         <activity android:name=".vista.prospectos.ProspectosListActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"></activity>
         <activity android:name=".vista.prospectos.ProspectoNuevoActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"></activity>
         <activity android:name=".vista.prospectos.FormularioActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"></activity>
         <activity android:name=".vista.productos.ProductosCreditoListActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"></activity>
         <activity android:name=".vista.productos.ProductoDetalleActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"></activity>
         <activity android:name=".vista.prospectos.ProspectoDatosActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"></activity>
         <activity android:name=".vista.prospectos.ProspectosDataListActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"></activity>
         <activity android:name=".vista.prospectos.FormularioFotos" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation" ></activity>
         <activity android:name=".vista.prospectos.FormularioFotosActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation" ></activity>
         <activity android:name=".vista.prospectos.FormularioRevisionActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation" ></activity>
         <activity android:name=".vista.prospectos.FormularioValidadorActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation" ></activity>
         <activity android:name=".vista.include.CapturarFirmaActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation" ></activity>
         <activity android:name=".vista.productos.ProductoListActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"></activity>
         <activity android:name=".vista.prospectos.FormularioDetallesActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"></activity>
         <activity android:name=".vista.clientes.ClientesListActivity"  android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"></activity>
         <activity android:name=".vista.prospectos.FormularioActivityTest" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"></activity>
         <activity android:name=".vista.clientes.ClienteDetalleActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"></activity>
         <activity android:name=".vista.imprimibles.ImprimiblesActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"></activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```